# Embed Flash using SWFObject with Strict Doctype

Tags: flash, html, doctype, swfobject

Having a problem embedding a flash chatroom under a doctype equaling strict using the SWFObject

Without the doctype of strict i lose the margin:auto usage under IE. Using the doctype of strict the flash chat room doesnt load properly at all. I read the swfobject embedding techniques for doctype of strict but can not actually get it. This is what i have below, but it squishes the flash together at top instead of expanding it at 100% in height

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Flashchat</title>
<link href="sitecss.asp" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="flash_swf">
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var so = new SWFObject("swf.swf", "videochat", "100%", "100%", "8", "#FFFFFF");
so.addVariable("rootPath", "http://www.domain.com/flashchat/");
so.addVariable("roomId", "Room");
so.addVariable("app", "chat/videochat.swf");
so.addVariable("uid", "somename");
so.addVariable("skin", "Lead Grey");
so.addParam("wmode", "opaque");
so.write("flash_chat_swf");
// ]]>
</script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

OK, i used javascript to resize the flash on page load

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function resize(){  
var frame = document.getElementById("flash_swf");  
var htmlheight = document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight;  
var windowheight = window.innerHeight;  
if ( htmlheight < windowheight ) { document.body.style.height = windowheight + "px"; frame.style.height = windowheight + "px"; }  
else { document.body.style.height = htmlheight + "px"; frame.style.height = htmlheight + "px"; }  
}
</script>

<body onload="resize()" onresize="resize()">
```

But, I have a menu on top that's 40px in height. So I had to set a margin for the DIV margin:40px 0 0 0;. Now the flash is being cutoff 40px too short. How do I set the htmlheight and windowheight within the javascript so its 40 pixels less (-40px) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the doc type has anything to do with your issue!
Are you using the last version of SWFObject (I think that the embed method you're using is old...) ?

Anyway, the line

```
so.write("flash_chat_swf");
```

should be replaced by

```
so.write("flash_swf"); // corresponds to the div id the flash should be written in
```

And please insert the java script code outside of the div.

Instead of manually resizing the window, you should implement this script: http://swffit.millermedeiros.com/ This works very well with swfobject.

Hope this helps!